# show my login name in the menu bar option not work

Tags: 17.04, bug-reporting

I have Ubuntu 17.4 working on DELL Inspiron 5551 by kernel package 4.10.0-22-generic , it have problem with option of: show my login name in the menu bar, it's always hidden even the option is active, so i reported here, and looking for fix , thank you.
[image: bug-17:04-show my login name not working]

Comment: So you want to show your Login Name using The `uname` command?

Comment: No it just to show the kernel pack that have the bug

Comment: There isn't problem with fresh copy of 16.02 ,It worked with 16.02 fresh install not upgrade to it or to 16.03 , just fresh install from DVD, CD, with out any fix

Answer (score 2):

you can try with the following command

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

if you want to go back and not show your name

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false
```

**The nice thing of this solution is that you won't need to install any additional software normally.**

EDIT: it seems that that there is a bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/1640409

and no solution was released so far

Comment: Thank you for your reply , that command just to mark and un mark the option at user account settings , but also will not appear in the  menu bar , it was already marked as in the picture .

Comment: Hi @Bassem , I updated my answer with a link to a bug report. I think for now  you can not do much. I would follow the link I sent you and see if there will be an update.

Comment: Hi @minidiable thank you for your reply, looks like no fix available for it till now, thank you

Comment: There isn't problem with fresh copy of 16.02 ,It worked with 16.02 fresh install not upgrade to it or to 16.03 , just fresh install from DVD, CD, with out any fix